# OpenSearch .net (C#) library: which one?

Tags: c#, .net, opensearch

i would like to add OpenSearch to my C# webapplication.
does someone recommend a certain .net library? or does a custom webapplication require a tailormade opensearch implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might help:
http://blog.unto.net/opensearch/add-opensearch-to-your-site-in-five-minutes/

Comment: that is just for redirecting search queries to google. how do you output searchresults in an opensearch xml format?

Comment: i thought that opensearch required xml searchresults, can you confirm this and/or explain it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want while-you-type suggestions, you need to have a search method on the server that searches and returns the results in JSON (not XML) format. If you don't need suggestions, you just need a method that responds to the search in a normal way by pushing HTML to the browser.

Have a look at Mozilla's official documentation for [creating an opensearch plugin for your site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/creating_opensearch_plugins_for_firefox) and [supporting search suggestions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Supporting_search_suggestions_in_search_plugins)

Comment: IE supports [suggestions returned as XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#dev_xmlsyntax). And as always, M$ put a few nice features in it you only get if you DON'T use the standard JSON.

Comment: @takrl, you won't catch me recommending that to anyone.

Comment: I won't recommend it either ... my comment was mainly triggered by the _not XML_ in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest OpenSearch.Net (an open source fork of elasticsearch-net).
Have a look into the git repo for getting started

https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-net

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32723039)